# Не получаю response от axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

Вообщем не получаю response от axios когда статус 400 когда к примеру статус 200 response получаю

вот код js :

```
axios.post('/api/auth/login', {...form}, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                   }
```

вот код backend express js:

```
router.post('/login',
    [
        check('email', 'Неккоректный email!').isEmail(),
        check('password', 'Неккоректный пароль').exists()
    ]
    ,
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const errors = validationResult(req);
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    errors: errors.array(),
                    message: 'Неккоректные данные при авторизации!'
                });
            }
            const {email, password} = req.body;
            const user = await User.findOne({ email });

            if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).json({message: 'Пользователь не найден!'});
            }

            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);


            if (!isMatch) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Неверный пароль!' });
            }

            const jwtSecret = 'fhiahifhio3yi1yior31ihf1y90143941hf1whifhsaf13rf';

            const token = jwt.sign(
                {userId: user.id},
                jwtSecret,
                {expiresIn: '1h'}
            );

            res.json({token, userId: user.id});

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

мне из response нужно получить message когда введен некорректный email или пароль

Comment: потому что `406` ответ уйдёт в `axios.post().catch`

Comment: @nörbörnën я делал через catch но оттуда я получаю только ошибку Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request). А мне нужно достать message из response. Или я что то не понял? Поясните пожалуйста)

Comment: вы всё поняли правильно. почитайте документацию https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо огромное получилось!!!